# Factory pattern with generics in java

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, abstract-factory

I'm having trouble implementing factory with generics for a specific use case

I have model classes:

```
class BaseModel { }

class ModelA extends BaseModel { }

class ModelB extends BaseModel { }
```

And corresponding services:

```
class Service<T extends BaseModel> { }

class ServiceA extends Service<ModelA> {}

class ServiceB extends Service<ModelB> {}
```

My Factory class, to create service according to the model it services:

```
class Factory {
    private Map<Class<? extends BaseModel>, Class<? extends Service>> registry;

    Factory(){
        registry = new HashMap<>();
        registry.put(ModelA.class, ServiceA.class);
        registry.put(ModelB.class, ServiceB.class);
    }

    Service getService(Class<? extends BaseModel> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        return registry.get(clazz).newInstance();
    }
}
```

And a class that uses the factory

```
class Handler<T extends BaseModel>{
    private Service<T> myService;

    Handler(Class<T> modelClass) {
        Factory fact = new Factory();
        try {
            myService = fact.getService(modelClass);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I get an warning for the line that uses the factory to get the service:

```
"Unchecked assignment 'Service' to 'Service<T>'"
```

I understand why I get the message, since the `getService` method returns `Service`, but I need `Service<T>` and puzzled about how I can change the code to get `Service<T>`

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: And what *return type* does the method `getService()` have? is it `Service` or `Service<T>` ?

Comment: You could use `<T extends BaseModel> Service getService(Class<T> clazz)` and cast your returned value to `Service<T>`. You will still get an unchecked warning in the method itself, but that's one of the weaknesses of runtime erasure of Java generics.

Comment: There are two problems:  First, there is no way to make a Map where different keys correspond to different generic types.  It simply can’t be done.  Second, there is no way to safely use reflection to create a generically typed object (like `ArrayList<String>` or `Service<T>`).  You would be better off eliminating generic typing from Service.  Can you show some examples of Service methods that use the model subtype?

Comment: @alfasin I would like it to be Service<T> but I'm I don't know how to make it happen.

Comment: @bcsb1001 If I need to cast then I can just use casting for it all instead no? 
If I'm staying with a warning then I can leave this implementation as it, don't you think?

Comment: @VGR basically I would like to create a service for the type the handler uses. My handler is generic but I have a service for each type it might receive. I wanted to keep the model separate from the business logic so I created a service for each type. I'm starting to think it's a wrong design for this case

Comment: Why does Service need to be generic?

Comment: @VGR The code sample doesn't reflect that. Since the service is exposing methods that should be in the context of the same model in the return value, I cannot assign it back to a generic like so (in the handler) "T myModel = myService.doSomethingAndReturnAModel()"

Comment: And that is why I asked you to provide an example of a Service method.  So, a Service essentially acts as a factory for model instances of a specific type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java generics and inheritance sometimes interact counter-intuitively, i.e. `Service<ModelA>` is not related (in terms of inheritance) to `Service<BaseModel>`. However, you can write two implementations of `getService()` and call the service constructors explicitly (not through reflection). Your Handler will need an instance of your Model, such that Java overriding will select the correct service-constructor for you.

What I haven't thought about in my original answer: you need to catch for all BaseModel implementations in your factory (overriding will pick the most specific method) and also your Service has to be implemented against an interface to pull the strings together.

```
class BaseModel { }

class ModelA extends BaseModel { }

class ModelB extends BaseModel { }

interface Service { }

class ServiceImplementation<T extends BaseModel> implements Service { }

class ServiceFactory {
    public static Service getService(ModelA model) { return new ServiceImplementation<ModelA>(); }
    public static Service getService(ModelB model) { return new ServiceImplementation<ModelB>(); }
    public static Service getService(BaseModel model) { 
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown Service Model");
    }
}

class Handler<T extends BaseModel> {
    private Service service;

    Handler(T model) {
        service = ServiceFactory.getService(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I can do that while keeping the handler generic. If you could expand your response it would be very helpful :)

Comment: I just edited my answer, tried to keep it simple. HTH

Comment: Thank you so much! This gives me an error "Cannot resolve method 'getService(T)' " anything you think I'm missing?

Comment: no, I should have tested the code, check my edited answer for what's been missing

Answer (score 2):

Here, you can capture the class as T and return a instance of it (with cast):

```
<T extends BaseModel> Service<T> getService(Class<T> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    return (Service<T>) registry.get(clazz).newInstance();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I get the unchecked case warning on this casting line

Comment: Yes, newInstance() returns object, this a unsafe cast, but if you receive only T extends BaseModel and register all cases you will never fail